# Control spotlight direction by slider

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

In ShadowMapDemo of HelixToolkit, direction of spotlight is controlled by UICompositeManipulator3D through a Camera 3D Model(CameraModel3D).
UICompositeManipulator3D has 3 circles which are controlled by mouse to change direction along local x, y and z axis.

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <hx:RenderTechniqueConverter x:Key="RenderTechniqueConverter" />
        <local:SliderToTransformConverterX x:Key="SliderToTransformConverterX"/>
    </Window.Resources>
<hx:SpotLight3D
                x:Name="spotLight"
                Direction="{Binding Camera1.LookDirection, Mode=OneWay}"
                OuterAngle="{Binding Camera1.FieldOfView}"
                Position="{Binding Camera1.Position, Mode=OneWay}"
                Range="{Binding Camera1.FarPlaneDistance}"
                Tag="{Binding DirectionalLightColorText}"
                Color="{Binding DirectionalLightColor}" />
          
            <hx:CameraModel3D x:Name="lightCamera" Camera="{Binding Camera1}" />
<hx:UICompositeManipulator3D
                x:Name="uic"
                CanRotateX="true"
                CanRotateY="true"
                CanRotateZ="true"
                CanTranslateX="False"
                CanTranslateY="False"
                CanTranslateZ="False"
                Diameter="2"
                TargetTransform="{Binding Transform, ElementName=lightCamera}" />
<StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Margin="3">DirectionX : </TextBlock>
                        <Slider
                            Width="180"
                            Margin="3"
                            Maximum="180"
                            Minimum="1"
                            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                            TickFrequency="1"
                            Value="{Binding TargetTransform,ElementName=uic,Converter={StaticResource SliderToTransformConverterX},ConverterParameter={x:Reference Name=uic},Mode=TwoWay}"
                             />
                    </StackPanel>
```

**Additionaly I would like to control it by three sliders, each for x,y and z axis**. I tried this and working -

```cs
public static ProjectionCamera Camera1 { private set; get; }
    Camera1 = new PerspectiveCamera 
            { 
                Position = new Point3D(0,5,0), 
                LookDirection = new Vector3D(0,-1,0), 
                UpDirection = new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 
                FarPlaneDistance = 5000, 
                NearPlaneDistance = 1,
                FieldOfView = 45
            };
public class SliderToTransformConverterX : IValueConverter
    {
         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
       UICompositeManipulator3D uICompositeManipulator3D = new UICompositeManipulator3D();
            uICompositeManipulator3D.Transform = value as Transform3D;
            if (uICompositeManipulator3D.Transform != null)
            {
                Vector3D xAxis = uICompositeManipulator3D.Transform.Transform(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0));
                var anglex = Vector3D.AngleBetween(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), uICompositeManipulator3D.Transform.Transform(xAxis));
                return Math.Floor(anglex);
            }
       return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double data = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
            UICompositeManipulator3D uICompositeManipulator3D = parameter as UICompositeManipulator3D;
            
            if (data % 1 == 0)
            {
                Transform3D previousTransforms = uICompositeManipulator3D.Transform;

                var m = uICompositeManipulator3D.Transform.Value.ToMatrix();
                m.DecomposeUniformScale(out var scale, out var rotation, out var translation);

                Vector3D localAxisX = uICompositeManipulator3D.Transform.Transform(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0));
                var angleX = Vector3D.AngleBetween(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), uICompositeManipulator3D.Transform.Transform(localAxisX));
                RotateTransform3D rotateAboutX = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(localAxisX, data - angleX), translation.X, translation.Y, translation.Z);
                
                Transform3DGroup transform3DGroup = new Transform3DGroup();
                transform3DGroup.Children.Add(previousTransforms);
                transform3DGroup.Children.Add(rotateAboutX);
                var anglex1 = Vector3D.AngleBetween(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), uICompositeManipulator3D.Transform.Transform(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0)));
                return transform3DGroup;
       }
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

       

    }
```

Similar code can be used for y and z axis.

**Is this a correct way ?**

**Is there any helper in SharpDX to do the same?**

**Advice me a better way**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly control the spot light direction if you don't want to use the manipulator.